# Is it required to add custom views in admin page in ModelAdmin class when we can do it normally by adding views in views.py and urls in urls.py?

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-admin, django-urls

According to django docs:

```
class MyModelAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    def get_urls(self):
        urls = super(MyModelAdmin, self).get_urls()
        my_urls = [
            url(r'^my_view/$', self.my_view),
        ]
        return my_urls + urls

    def my_view(self, request):
        # ...
       context = dict(
           # Include common variables for rendering the admin template.
           self.admin_site.each_context(request),
           # Anything else you want in the context...
           key=value,
        )
        return TemplateResponse(request, "sometemplate.html", context)
```

If I am not wrong, we can do the same thing by adding url in urls.py and the views in views.py as it is normally done then, what is the use of introducing this way? I am a newbie to django and I may be missing something here.
Can you please provide an example where we cannot do it in views.py and we must use the above method?
Any guidance/help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think I figured out, both of them can be used to do the same thing but the key difference is that the views which you write using above method will belong to **admin app** while the general views in views.py belongs to the particular app in you have written.
Hence, the url in ModelAdmin need to be called using name **admin:url_name** since the url goes as **admin/my_views/** in given example.